# ebay GetOrders API using OutputSelector and SortOrder - .Net SDK

Tags: c#, .net, ebay-api

I am using ebay .Net SDK. Everything is working fine except following requirements:

1. Using of **OutputSelector** to boost performance
2. Unable to use **SortingOrder**, while showing records.
3. Total income/amount sold for specified time range i.e. Total amount across all calls of the pagination without looping through pages and aggregating it manually.

Here is the code which I am using:

```
var apicall = new GetOrdersCall(context);
//apicall.ApiRequest.OutputSelector = new StringCollection(new String[] { "Order.OrderID", "Order.Total" });
apicall.ApiRequest.Pagination = new PaginationType
{
    EntriesPerPage = Util.RecordsPerPage(),
    PageNumber = int.Parse(Request.Form["pageNumber"])
};
var fltr = new TimeFilter(Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["dateFrom"] + "T00:00:00.000Z"), Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["dateTo"] + "T23:59:59.999Z"));
var statusCodeType = (OrderStatusCodeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderStatusCodeType), Request.Form["statusCode"]);
var orders = apicall.GetOrders(fltr, TradingRoleCodeType.Seller, statusCodeType);
```

Please assist me how to use these 3 functionality as well.

Answer (score 0):

After much efforts I got the way for it:

```
var request = new GetOrdersRequestType
{
    //OutputSelector = new StringCollection {"OrderID","Total"},
    CreateTimeFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["dateFrom"] + "T00:00:00.000Z"),
    CreateTimeTo = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["dateTo"] + "T23:59:59.999Z"),
    OrderStatus = (OrderStatusCodeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderStatusCodeType), Request.Form["statusCode"]),
    OrderRole = TradingRoleCodeType.Seller,
    Pagination = new PaginationType
        {
            EntriesPerPage = Util.RecordsPerPage(),
            PageNumber = int.Parse(Request.Form["pageNumber"])
        }
};

var apicall = new GetOrdersCall(context)
    {
        ApiRequest = request,
        OutputSelector =
            new string[]
                {
                    "OrderID", "Total", "PaidTime", "eBayPaymentStatus",
                    "PaymentMethod", "Title", "PageNumber", "PaginationResult.TotalNumberOfPages"
                }
    };

apicall.Execute();
var orders = apicall.ApiResponse.OrderArray;
```

Comment: I know this is old...but when using the pagination.  If there is more than 1 page of results.  How do you get the next page?  Do you have to do the whole request again?